# Capturing shared_ptr in lambda using std::move

Tags: c++, lambda, shared-ptr

In following code `std::move` in lambda capture list felt unnecessary to me, but compiler does seem to need it.

As there is extra code for copying shared_ptr is generated if I don't use `std::move`.

Question is, why compiler can't optimise this on its own.

```
template<typename T>
std::function<void(void)> prepLambdaImpl(std::shared_ptr<T> aptr) {
#ifdef CONVERT_SHARED_PTR_TO_XVALUE
  return [aptr=std::move(aptr)]
#else
  return [aptr]
#endif
  {
      printf("use count: %ld\n", aptr.use_count());
  };
}
```

Working example: https://godbolt.org/z/W3oWEjsjK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Automatic move only happens in return statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return#Automatic_move_from_local_variables_and_parameters) in some specific circumstances, which are not met here.

Last usage doesn't trigger a move instead of a copy.

The [as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) allows optimization as long than observable behaviour is unchanged. Whereas we know the 2 forms are equivalent, it is not easy to know. Especially move and copy are unrelated functions; so optimizers only uses the copy code to try to optimize it (and it probably misses some extra information as invariant of the class (as refcounter not 0 at start of function)).

Comment: Checked same thing for `std::string` and results are kinda same. So, I think my expectation from compiler to optimize lambda capture on it own was incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Without `std::move` the `std::shared_ptr` will be copied into the lambda. Copying (but not moving) a `std::shared_ptr` requires incrementing its atomic reference count (and decrementing it again once the copy is destroyed).

In theory a compiler would be allowed to remove the atomic increment from the copy and the atomic decrement from the `aptr` parameter's destructor since they cancel, assuming it makes sure that no other thread can observe an intermediate state, however compilers tend to be conservative and don't optimize atomic operations because that is often not what users except to happen.

Comment: In fact, in this case, it is straight up forbidden to simplify the code generally speaking. As the atomic decrease should be done with "release"  memory instruction.

Comment: @ALX23z I don't think that is a problem. The release memory order is only relevant if an acquire in another thread sees the modified value, which is impossible if both increment and decrement were canceled.

Comment: That's not how it works. It doesn't matter if the value is unchanged. What's important is that release operation was triggered. It enforces quite a few things

Comment: @ALX23z What would be a case where it makes a difference here? As far as I can tell any acquire in another thread which observes the value after the decrement may just as well observe the value before the increment. There is no way to differentiate the two situations and so it should be equivalent to increment and decrement being optimized away, making the release operation irrelevant.

Comment: The difference is that "release" operation affects what happens at this thread as well. Regardless of whether anything happens at another or whether there is or isn't an acquire at some point.

Comment: @ALX23z In what way? The only effect a release operation has is that it introduces synchronization points with acquire (or consume) operations. It doesn't affect sequencing in a single thread.

Comment: It adds various restrictions what memory shuffling a compiler can perform. One also needs to call different memory operations for release (depends on architecture)